# How connect Google colab to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, connection, ip, bigdata, google-colaboratory

**I need to connect Google Colab with Cassandra to make keyspace tables and insert large volumes of data and make queries in Cassandra from Google Colab but I always have connection problems**

I have tried almost everything, downloading connectors, I have used the Google Cloud API, I have used Datastax, I have gone to the Cassandra version of Killercosa from Playground and I have created keyspace and tables, but since I have 15 thousand data, I cannot insert into for 15 thousand data and my task is in doing everything from Google Colab, I would appreciate someone who can help me with a manual

Answer (score 1):

There are vaious ways with which you could connect to a Cassandra-compatible database. Since you haven't provided any snippets or other details, I'm going to make some assumptions.

There are examples of Google Colab notebooks at these places that you can follow,

- [CassIO](https://cassio.org/start_here/)
- [Code examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/astra-db-vector/get-started/examples.html)

Hope these helps. Happy to edit my answer once you provide other additional details of your setup or end goals.